# Click and .next() - A better way?

Tags: jquery

Example - [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/s4nYu/2/)

So I built a simple slider using the following code:

```
activeSlide.removeClass("active")
    .next().addClass("active")

if (activeSlide.next().length === 0) {
    firstSlide.addClass("active");
}
```

It all works lovely. I thought I could perhaps use something similar to create a forward and back button:

```
control.on('click', 'a.next', function() {
    activeSlide = activeSlide
        .next().removeClass("active")
        .next().addClass("active");
});
```

It works okay for the middle slides (a little slow?), but doesn't seem to trigger on the first or last.

If anyone has a suggestion for a better way, or has an idea on how to tweak the above code, it would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's three problems with your code:

1. The setup of the event handler (the second block in the question) is inside the function that is called by the timer (only seen on the jsFiddle). Move it outside or you will set up multiple event handlers.
2. On the fourth line in the second code block you are calling `next()` which means that you are removing the `active` class from the next block instead of the active one.
3. The `activeSlide` variable will be caught by the closure of the event handler function and will probably not point to the currently active slide when the button is hit. Reinitialize the `activeSlide` with `$('.slide.active')` inside the event handler.

```
control.on('click', 'a.next', function() {
    $('.slide.active')
        removeClass("active")
        .next().addClass("active");
});
```